# Dispatch queue not loading records into tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Sorry in advance if I'm making a rookie mistake but I'm new to Swift.

I'm following a tutorial online and so far I have this->

```
    func loadData () {
   posts = [CKRecord]()

    let publicData = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Post", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil))
    query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
    publicData.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (results:[CKRecord]?, error:Error?) -> Void in
        if let posts = results {
            self.posts = posts
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.refresh.endRefreshing()
                print("refreshed")
            })
        }
    }

}
```

Even though the output reads refreshed none of the records are showing up. This is just a portion of the code that I believe I have narrowed down the issue too. When I create records they show up in my cloud kit dashboard but they aren't being pulled into the tableview.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Update: Here are the datasource methods

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return posts.count



}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    if posts.count == 0 {
        return cell
    }

    let post = posts[indexPath.row]

    if let postContent = post["content"] as? String {
        let dateFormat = DateFormatter()
        dateFormat.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
        let dateString = dateFormat.string(from: post.creationDate!)

        cell.textLabel?.text = postContent
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateString
    }


    return cell

}
```

Comment: What you see in a table view depends on how your table view data source methods are configured. Could you show those?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I posted the datasource methods.

Comment: Were you set delegate & datasource for your tableview?  When you reloadtableview ,  is it enter "numberOfRowsInSection"

Comment: Thanks for posting that! So put a breakpoint on, say, the `cell.textLabel?.text` line. Is it getting executed? If not, there's your problem, and you can use the debugger to trace back until you figure out where things are going wrong.

Comment: cross check whether datasource of tableview is set. or try adding`self.tableview.datasource = self` in` viewdidload`

Comment: @Vinodh I tried adding that line and I got the error "Value of type 'StreamTableViewController' has no member 'tableview' "

Update- needed to use uppercase S in source and didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @matt The breakpoint does not execute when I reload, only when I post a record. Is it possible my reload function has an incorrect variable?

Comment: Well, keep debugging. You are setting `self.posts = posts` which is assigned from `results`. Well, put a breakpoint there and _look_ at `results` or `posts` and see what it is. If it's an empty array, you're going to get an empty table.

Comment: @Matt it's an empty array. Could I have forgotten something on the CloudKit Dashboard end of things?

Comment: My first response would be that you have no records of type "Post".

Comment: @matt I checked that and even tried creating a new record type with a different name. I'm honestly clueless at this point

Comment: No you're not! You've completely debugged this part of the code!! Very well done. You now know that the problem has nothing to do with the dispatch queue, the table, or any of the things you asked about. The problem is that you're performing a CKQuery and it's coming back with an empty array and you don't know why. That's what your question needs to be about.

Comment: @matt This is true! I appreciate your help. Is it possible that I am creating the records with the content and loading them without the actual content? I'm new to all of this so I'm wondering if a certain record can have different contents and you can display just a portion of it's data.

Comment: You should rewrite the whole question and show how you create the records and upload them, and show the query just as you are showing it now. This is now a Cloud Kit question pure and simple.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40434502/cloud-kit-pulling-empty-array

Here is the link for the follow up question in case anyone has a similar problem..